# Robot framework keywords are showing "No keyword with name xyz"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-server

I am new to robot framework and python, I am facing problem with the keywords, which shows me the error `No keyword with name xyz`. For an example in file `csv_handler.py`

```
import all library and key words

class csv_handler:
    @keyword("Extract text from CSV file")
    def extract_text_from_CSV_file(self, file_name):
        execution_mode = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${EXECUTION_MODE}")
        download_folder = config_file[execution_mode]["download_folder"]
        userName = getpass.getuser()
        localUserName = userName.strip("adm-")
        download_folder = download_folder.replace("<local_user>", localUserName)
        data = []
        with open(download_folder.strip() + file_name, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                data.append(row)
        return data
```

I need a new keyword in the file `csv_handler.py` so I just copy the old keyword and did some modification to it made the new keyword. Now the new file looks like

```
import all library and key words

class csv_handler:
    @keyword("Extract text from CSV file")
    def extract_text_from_CSV_file(self, file_name):
        execution_mode = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${EXECUTION_MODE}")
        download_folder = config_file[execution_mode]["download_folder"]
        userName = getpass.getuser()
        localUserName = userName.strip("adm-")
        download_folder = download_folder.replace("<local_user>", localUserName)
        data = []
        with open(download_folder.strip() + file_name, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                data.append(row)
        return data

    @keyword("Extract text from created CSV file")
    def extract_text_from_CSV_file(self, file_name):
        execution_mode = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${EXECUTION_MODE}")
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        upload_folder = cwd + config_file[execution_mode]["upload_folder"]
        userName = getpass.getuser()
        localUserName = userName.strip("adm-")
        upload_folder = upload_folder.replace("<local_user>", localUserName)
        data = []
        with open(upload_folder.strip() + file_name, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                data.append(row)
        return data
```

After making my new keyword in the file `csv_handler.py` , if I go to the **.robot** file and try to run the test script the test script where I used the old key word, that throws me error "No keyword with name old keyword" and for the result script fails.

I tried to restart my vscode, laptop but not got chance to fix it. Your help will be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious except indentation and syntax errors. I assume these are result of copying and modifying your code for SO. However, can you fix the code in your question so that I can copyo&paste to my editor? You could run robot with TRACE option and see if it shows any errors.

Comment: There are missed underlines in method names in Python code:
`def oldkeyword_which is working` - should be like `def oldkeyword_which_is_working`

The same issue for the another name.  

Python method names couldn't have spaces in them.

BTW, check the console log in your IDE, I guess there are should be red errors (because of the mentioned space issue)

Comment: Hi, I changed after getting your comments. it was confusing so I directly pasted the correct code

Comment: NOTE: You have the SAME real method names for both keywords! I.e. `def extract_text_from_CSV_file`.   Please, change one of the names to have them different and try again.  If the error is still here, could you add it just in case your problematic robot-file and in addition copy-paste the real error from the test report?

Comment: Nice find, Sam. This is why it is essential to lint your code. Always run at least pylint. I also run pyflakes, mypy and black.